# Vista previa al compartir url usando property="og:image"

Tags: html, meta-tags

Quiero cambiar la imagen que se muestra como vista previa en una url al compartirla por messenger o mensaje texto, intente de este forma pero no funciono, que otra alternativa hay?

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
```

gracias

Answer (score 5):

Debe funcionar, pero debes considerar que la imagen debe estar disponible, al parecer la que defines (http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg) no existe o no se puede acceder, este es un ejemplo correcto.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://picsum.photos/id/866/300/300" />
```

La mínima medida permitida para la imagen debe ser 200x200 pixeles.

---

Ejemplo:

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<title>Stackoverflow Rocks!</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="This is my title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:description" content="hello fellas this is my description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://picsum.photos/id/866/200/200" />

</head>

</html>
```

De esta forma se mostrará la imagen al compartirla :

Facebook:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Whatsapp:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisa la [**documentación**](https://ogp.me/).